# Spacing for radio buttons and their labels in Material Design 3

Tags: material-design

The [spec](https://m3.material.io/components/radio-button/overview) for radio buttons doesn't specify lots of important spacing:

- Between the radio button and its label.
- Between each radio button in a group of radio buttons.
- Between the radio button and the left edge of the screen (might be 16dp but it isn't specified).

Is there an "official" spec for these measurements?

Answer (score 0):

In the [API documentation for RadioButton in Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#RadioButton(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.material3.RadioButtonColors,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource)) there's an example that uses a 16dp padding for the "row" containing the radio button and its label and a 16dp margin between the radio button and its label. While not an official spec it's at least an example from one of the canonical implementations in Android.